# Denseness and non-measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I made up a question for myself and tried to answer it. I'm not completely sure of my question and answer, since I lack a grounding in analysis (the tragedy of doing physics then mathematical biology). Thanks for any corrections.

### Question

Given some non Lebesgue-measurable set, $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $a<b\in\mathbb{R}$, $A\cap[a,b]$ is also not Lebesgue-measurable, is $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

### Attempted proof:

Try a contradiction. Assume $A$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\exists \epsilon>0,k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $[k,k+\epsilon]\subset \mathbb{R}\setminus A$. Then $\lambda\left(A\cap[k,k+\epsilon]\right)=\lambda(\emptyset)=0$: contradicting the assumption all such sets are non-measurable. Thus $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: More directly, you can observe that since the empty set is measurable, the assumption "$A\cap[a,b]$ is nonmeasurable for all $a<b$" implies "$A\cap[a,b]$ is nonempty for all $a<b$", and the last quoted property is what "$A$ is dense in $\mathbb R$" means.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks perfectly fine to me.